# Is the masterpage in 14 hive or backend db

Tags: master-page

Our Masterpage got corrupted and there is no local backup. Where is it located? If is in file share like 14 hive then I can get a copy from system admin from last night backup? Or if is in the sql backend then I can get the dba to send me the aspx file.

I looked at here but dont see the custom masterpage that portal site is uses. C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which master page?

v4, default and minimal are taken from the _layouts virtual directory (\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS)
You should have identical copies in \14\TEMPLATE\GLOBAL

Custom master pages are in your feature's folder, or in the DB once provisioned and customized through SharePoint Designer.

Answer (score 1):

Your 14 Hive should not be a file share, ever!

If you mean file system rather than a share, then ok :)

Yes, it's stored in 14\Template\Global (I think, look for a Global folder), or in 14\Template\Layouts.

It's recommended though to try to restore the file to the site definition, but using the link in Site Settings, and pasting in the URL to the masterpage file in the Master Page Gallery.

Comment: I dont see the custom masterpages thou?

Comment: Oh is it customised? Then it will be versioned. Can you recovery from the version history?

Answer (score 1):

Masterpages are typically version controlled within the site collection.  If you go to the affected site and go to Site Actions, Site Settings and look in the Master Page Gallery, you should be able to find your masterpage and roll it back to a working version.

Comment: Will try it. Good suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If the masterpage was deployed via a solution package (WSP) then you should find the original ASPX file under the folder for the associated Feature (i.e. \14\TEMPLATE\FEATURES).

Comment: good thought. It was created with sp designer.